# Updating a WHERE clause to check if a value is NOT in a separate table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, where

I have a query which uses a `WHERE` clause, and I *happen* to use the exact same `WHERE` clause in **many** queries on this table (et al).

The query is:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(DW, [AtDateTime]) AS [Day of Week]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [Number of Searches]
    ,CAST(CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) 
         / COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, [AtDateTime])) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) 
       AS [Average Searches per Day]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [NumFound] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       AS [Number of Searches with no Results]
    ,CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [NumFound] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) 
       AS [Percent of Searches with no Results]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[SearchHistory] 
WHERE 
    [CustomerNumber] <> '1234' AND [CustomerNumber] <> '5678'
GROUP BY DATENAME(DW, [AtDateTime]), DATEPART(DW, [AtDateTime])
ORDER BY DATEPART(DW, [AtDateTime])
```

The part I wish to change is the `WHERE` clause, to instead allow me to use a table so that if I have to add a customer number to be ignored, I don't have to update *all* my queries. (And there are quite a few queries that have this same `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: If the Customer exclusions are currently specific to the query execution, why would moving them to a shared table/ work table not introduce false sharing? In a normal application, customers would typically be arbitrary & thus specific to a single query execution. I would suggest this question either omits important facts as to generality necessary for the solution to work correctly, or overlooks the issue of sharing.

Comment: @ThomasW - what is this "false sharing" you're talking about?  Do you have a reference for that?  I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @ThomasW The requirements for this are that certain customers we have (which we use a lot for testing) must be excluded from certain reports, as they skew the results.

Comment: Thanks EBrown. This clarifies that the set to be excluded is common across users & query invocations.

Comment: @ThomasW Indeed. Sorry I wasn't clear about that initially - I should have made that more apparent. :)

Comment: @MaxVernon -- perhaps a better recognized term would be "incorrect scope". What was described did involve changing an input from a completely independent parameter, to being a cross-user, cross-invocation shared DB table. This change crosses 2 scope boundaries. Given additional context the described scope seems OK, but if it were not this would manifest as "erroneous sharing".

Comment: The described approach was also reminiscent of a whole lot of legacy work-table implementation (~1000 tables) in a major application I have responsibility for. In this regard I raised the possible "work table" nature as a question :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a table to hold the customer numbers to be excluded, then exclude those rows using a `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExcludedCustomers
(
    CustomerNumber VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_ExcludedCustomers
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT INTO dbo.ExcludedCustomers (CustomerNumber)
VALUES ('1234')
    , ('5678');


SELECT
    <....>
FROM [DB].[dbo].[SearchHistory] 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.ExcludedCustomers ec
        WHERE ec.CustomerNumber = SearchHistory.CustomerNumber
    )
    <...>;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerExclusions
(
  CustomerNumber VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY -- Is CustomerNumber *really* a string?
);

INSERT dbo.CustomerExclusions(CustomerNumber) VALUES('1234'),('5678');
```

Now your `WHERE` clause across all queries becomes:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CustomerExclusions AS c
  WHERE c.CustomerNumber = SearchHistory.CustomerNumber
)
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Customer numbers *have* to be a string for cross-compatibility with the AS/400. (At least for now, we're working on a fix for it.)

Comment: @EBrown Uh, ugh.

Answer (score -3):

There are important questions/ potential problems with your proposed approach. For sure, you can exclude easily enough via a 'Customer Number exclusion' work table:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].Work_ExcludeCustomer
  WHERE CustomerNumber = SearchHistory.CustomerNumber
)
```

But now, what were "query parameters" -- fully dynamic & independent, per-query and per-user -- are turning into "shared persistent state in the database".

Some questions & relevant points:

1. should the Customer Exclusion info be separate, per-User or per-Session?  you can add a 'SessionID' parameter to distinguish these, but essentially you're recreating a hoary old "Work Table" pattern.
2. perhaps a NOT IN(...) clause could be preferable? that can be parameterized dynamically, up to the limit of 2100 parameters.
3. perhaps revisit your code/ infrastructure to build queries & binds parameters, if you currently rely on fixed parameter numbers;  improving this will enable modularity & use of an IN or NOT IN (?, ?, ?..) clauses with variable number of parameters.

Suggested approach:

```
WHERE [CustomerNumber] NOT IN (?, ?, ?)
```

With bindings '1234', '5678', '6789' etc to the NOT IN() parameters & subsequent logical query parameters bound to the appropriate numbering dynamically.

Comment: Use of NOT IN (...) and/or dynamically building query text is an anti-pattern, and will result in lower performance than the set-based approaches recommended by Aaron and myself.

Comment: For an excellent read on the differences, check [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) post.

Comment: @MaxVernon -- replacing dynamic parameters with "shared" data or work tables may introduce false sharing, which is far more of an anti-pattern. Since nobody else has specifically considered or established that this is not an issue, it is absolutely valid to raise this concern; nor should it be trivially down-voted.